# Is there a way to add and remove accounts from device via Android adb?

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, adb

I am performing some automated tests on an app, and I am in this situation where after I log in with a user, it's google account gets added to the device accounts, so after the first executions, the test won't work again because the account is already linked in the device.

Manually by GUI, you can go to settings > accounts > manage accounts > account > remove account

My question is: is there any way to perform this with a adb shell command?

I have tried:

```
adb shell pm remove-user 0
adb shell am kill —user 0
adb shell pm disable-user app.package.name —user 0
```

But non of these worked, I get this message

> Error: couldn't remove user id 0

Comment: The commands yo tried are for deleting Android users (the multi-user feature of Android), not accounts. So even if they would work they would not do what you want. My approach would be to write a small helper app that deletes the Google account when the app is started using the documented [AccountManager API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager).